# Powershell command not processing log consistently

Tags: powershell, dos, pipeline

I have a bit of code that monitors a putty log file using

```
Get-Content $LogPath -tail 0 -wait | Select-String -Pattern $Alarms -SimpleMatch | 
      ForEach-Object { & $PageApp SendSubScriber $PageUser `"$_`"}
```

I'll post the complete script below but this is the 'brains' of a script that will monitor a log file in real time for an array of strings ($Alarms) and pass on the complete string to a command line paging application ($PageApp).

If I run this script and manually add lines to the file being monitored that contain an alarm string I get paged every time as desired. i.e.

```
Add-Content $LogPath "Low-Battery"
```

The problem is that When this device generates events, putty writes to the log file but nothing happens... If I open and close the putty log I'll then get paged with the last event. I imagine this has something to do with the log file appearing in use by another program. But even with the putty session running I can manually inject alarm strings using add-content and I'll get paged properly, it's only when the serial device writes to the file.

Is there a way to debug the get-content command so i can see why it isn't passing strings to the dos command? I Do see output in the console window when things work properly but nothing when this serial device is writing to the putty log.

This is the entire code:

```
#Log To Process for Events
$LogFile = "SRAS-$(Get-Date -format dd-MM-yyyy).log"
$LogPath = "C:\SRAS\Logs\$LogFile"

#Output File for Paging
$PageFile = "PAGES-$(Get-Date -format dd-MM-yyyy).log"
$PagePath = "C:\SRAS\Pages\$PageFile"

#Variables for Paging
$PageApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ISS\Air Messenger Pro 7\SendCmd.exe"
$PageUser = "Test"

#Strings to monitor for
$Alarms = @("AC/BATT_PWR","OVERTEMP","ILA_DC-FEED","LOW-BATTERY","FO_RF-LINKB","FO_RF-LINKA","FO_DATALINK")

#Check if Needed Files Exist. If Not Create Them.
if (-not (Test-Path $LogPath))
    { New-Item $LogPath -ItemType file -Value "[$(Get-Date)] - New File Created `n"| Out-Null}
Else {
    echo "$LogFile Already Exists - appending to file"
    }
if (-not (Test-Path $PagePath))
    { New-Item $PagePath -ItemType file | Out-Null}
else {
    echo "$PageFile Already Exists - appending to file"
    }

#Variable to check if putty.exe is running
$putty_proc = get-process -name putty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Start PuTTy if it isn't running
if ($putty_proc -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Opening Putty Session for Logging"
    &"C:\tools\Software\putty.exe" -load "SRAS - Logging" 
    }
#If Putty is already Running, Kill and restart to generate log file with current date
else
    {
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping Current Putty Session..."
    Stop-Process $putty_proc
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Done"
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Opening Putty Session for Logging"
    &"C:\tools\Software\putty.exe" -load "SRAS - Logging" 
    }

Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Starting job for file $LogPath"


Get-Content $LogPath -tail 0 -wait | Select-String -Pattern $Alarms -SimpleMatch | 
      ForEach-Object { & $PageApp SendSubScriber $PageUser `"$_`"}
```

The reason for the $PagePath and $PageFile variables was because initially I was just putting alarms in a text file using out-file which did work without an issue.

Comment: I Just noticed today that this works as it should only if the event generated by the serial device is the first item in the array (AC/BATT_PWR).

Comment: Just tested the critical code you have here and it works for me.  My only thought is that the OS is not flushing the data to disk, and get-content doesn't see it until it gets flushed.  I used to work for a co. that makes file replication software, and that is something we ran into with IIS logs.  The OS wouldn't flush writes to the log file until it had 64K of writes.  However, since the changes were in cache, the changes were shown when the file was opened with notepad--they just hadn't flushed to disk yet.  Doesn't explain your last comment, but it's my only idea of what might be going on.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem lies in using foreach-object in the pipe. Originally I was trying to use

    Get-Content $LogPath -tail 0 -wait | Select-String -Pattern $Alarms -SimpleMatch | & $PageApp sendsubscriber $pageuser `"$_`"

but the quotes around $_ don't get passed on. The dos application requires the double quotes around the text to be sent to the paging terminal but I could only seem to get the passed using a script block in the foreach-object command. Using alternatives like the out-file i mentioned before work as desired. Any tips on getting the quotes passed around "$_"?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of pulling my hair out I've finally solved the problem.

Initially when i wrote this, it was on a development setup running windows 7 and all tests showed that it was working. It wasn't until I moved this script to the server it would be running on that I had the issue. The server is running Windows server 2008 R2.

As mentioned in the question if I'd open the log file I'd then get paged, I was CONVINCED it had something to do with the file appearing in use by another application, putty caching its output, etc... But while i had windows explorer open in the log file directory and hit F5 i got paged with alarms as well.

I don't know enough about OS's to really explain it but from what I can figure, when putty writes to the file windows isn't seeing the file as being updated and in turn neither is powershell. When i'd `Add-Content` to manually write to the file it's last modified property updated instantly and I'd get a page, I can only speculate that this is a windows problem as google had plenty of examples of server 2008 not updating files/directories properly.

The Fix

```
while($true)
{
$now = Get-Date

#Log To Process for Events
$LogFile = "SRAS-$(Get-Date -format dd-MM-yyyy).log"
$LogPath = "C:\SRAS\Logs\$LogFile"

#Output File for Paging
$PageFile = "PAGES-$(Get-Date -format dd-MM-yyyy).log"
$PagePath = "C:\SRAS\Pages\$PageFile"

#Variables for Paging
$PageHeader = "SRAS ALARM:"
$PageApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ISS\Air Messenger Pro 7\SendCmd.exe"
$PageUser = "Test"

#Strings to monitor for
$Alarms = @("AC/BATT_PWR","OVERTEMP","ILA_DC-FEED","LOW-BATTERY","FO_RF-LINKB","FO_RF-LINKA","FO_DATALINK")

#Check if Needed Files Exist. If Not Create Them.
if (-not (Test-Path $LogPath))
    { New-Item $LogPath -ItemType file -Value "[$(Get-Date)] - New File Created`n"| Out-Null}
Else {
    echo "$LogFile Already Exists - appending to file"
    }
if (-not (Test-Path $PagePath))
    { New-Item $PagePath -ItemType file | Out-Null}
else {
    echo "$PageFile Already Exists - appending to file"
    }

#Variable to check if putty.exe is running
$putty_proc = get-process -name putty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Start PuTTy if it isn't running
if ($putty_proc -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Opening Putty Session for Logging"
    &"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "SRAS - Logging" 
    }
#If Putty is already Running, Kill and restart to generate log file with current date
else
    {
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping Current Putty Session..."
    Stop-Process $putty_proc
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Done"
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Opening Putty Session for Logging"
    &"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "SRAS - Logging" 
    }

#Start Backround Job processing Log File
Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Starting job for file $LogPath"
$latest = Start-Job -Arg $LogPath, $Alarms, $PagePath, $PageHeader, $PageApp, $PageUser -ScriptBlock {
    param($a_LogPath,$a_Alarms,$a_PagePath, $a_PageHeader, $a_PageApp, $a_PageUser)

    # wait until the file exists, just in case
    while(-not (Test-Path $a_LogPath)){ sleep -sec 10 }

    Get-Content $a_LogPath -tail 0 -wait | Select-String -inputobject {$_.substring(9,27)} -Pattern $a_Alarms -SimpleMatch | foreach {& $a_PageApp SendSubScriber $a_PageUser `"$a_PageHeader $_`"}

   }

# wait until day changes, or whatever would cause new log file to be created
while($now.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){ 
#This forces a refresh of the log file (server 2008 glitch?)
get-content $LogPath | Out-Null
sleep -Sec 10 }

# kill the job and start over
Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping job for file $LogPath"
$latest | Stop-Job
}
```

The solution was the sixth line from the bottom. use a `Get-Content` on the log file which forces a refresh. This is part of the while loop that is looking for the date to change every 10 seconds. To Me this doesn't seem optimal but I don't know enough about scripting to make it any better.

The main part is run as a background job, filtering the log file in real time and sends events with desired strings on to the paging application.

There's some slight modifications to the 'critical' code i posted before but that's just for my own filtering purposes.